# Check if a request referer is a search engine

Tags: python

Does anyone know a reliable way to check whether the referrer of a HTTP request was a search engine or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a Django middleware object that offers this functionality: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/197/ . The logic can be extracted to work in a non-Django Python setting.

The method used here is to check the referring url to determine if it matches a given pattern (the presence of a parameter 'q', for example).